# Can never boot latest-installed kernel but can always boot older-installed ones, no matter what those kernel versions are

Tags: boot, grub2

Running Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS with kernel 5.4.0-67-generic; 64-bit.

I switch on my PC and the Grub boot menu appears. The topmost item listed is 'Ubuntu'. I select that but get dumped into emergency mode with an invitation to check out the journal or enter the root password 'for maintenance'. However, if, when the Grub boot menu appears, I select the next item down in the list, 'advanced options', and then select from the menu it displays the next most recent kernel, the OS boots just fine, without any issues. I regularly update my PC and it does not matter what kernel versions I have, so it's not something to do with a particular kernel version or versions, it's always whatever latest kernel that's installed that won't boot but the previous latest one always does.

My PC was at least ten years old and 32-bit, running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, so I upgraded the motherboard, CPU and RAM to 64-bit. I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 but, just as it was about to finish, it threw up a dialog box saying it couldn't. I installed my current OS without any apparent issues, but this is when the above problem started and has been going on for months now.

Comment: Add computer specs and Ubuntu version to question.  You are saying PC will not boot right with new kernel, but will boot with new kernel when it is replaced by newer kernel?  How long has this been happening?

Comment: This sounds odd.  There are kernels that don't work, but they always don't work.  You need to use older kernel till an updated kernel arrives and works, but the kernel giving problem still gives problem if used.  Something is wonky with your system, if you have not done something to it.  One suggestion would be to back up data and do a clean install.  Provide more info and might get better answer.

Comment: Added extra information.

Comment: Thinking it might more hardware, than Ubuntu.  Some how a piece of hardware is taking more time to engage/warmup/something than Ubuntu loads, but does work after you go though grub recovery.  Did you upgrade PSU also, new MB/CPU might take more power.  Would shutoff and check every connection.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the install of Ubuntu 20.04 failing right near the end, possibly the point Grub 2 was being installed and setting up. I've noticed that, after the kernel gets updated, the symlinks in / and /boot point to the wrong kernel versions and/or the symlinks to initrd.img and/or initrd.img.old likewise point to the wrong versions, eg: the symlink to the new kernel version points to the previous one and/or vice versa but 'manually' correcting them hasn't stopped the boot-up problem.